# Groovy xml dynamic coding

Tags: xml, groovy, streamingmarkupbuilder

I wish to create a dynamic XML file using inputs from the user(say an invoice list). As an input the Groovy script taken in number of items and based on the user entry, inputs the attributes per Invoice.
Could you please guide me on the block of code where i should apply looping logic?

Sample:-

```
Enter the total number of invoices: 
3
Enter the invoice 1 details:
26354
15000
17-12-2017
Harry
Enter the invoice 2 details:
16514
28000
24-09-2017
James
```

Expected output:-

```
<invoices>
<invoice number='26354'>
<price>15000.0</price>
<date>17-17-2017</date>
<customer>Clinton</customer>
</invoice>
<invoice number='16514'>
<price>28000.0</price>
<date>24-08-2017</date>
<customer>Mark</customer>
</invoice>
</invoices>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can define your data as list of maps.
- Use `StreamingMarkupBuilder` to create the xml.
- You haven't mentioned the root element name, and `invoiceRequest` is used as sample to make it well-formed xml, change its name as needed.

Follow in-line comments.

Here you go:

```
//Define your data as list of maps as shown below
def data = [ 
             [number: 26354, price: 15000, date: '17-12-2017', customer: 'Clinton'],
         [number: 16514, price: 28000, date: '24-08-2017', customer: 'Mark']
           ]

def xml = new groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    //Change the root element as needed instead of invoiceRequest
    invoiceRequest {
    invoices {
           //Loop thru list and create invoice elements
           data.each { inv ->
              invoice (number: inv.number) {
                 price (inv.price as double)
                 date (inv.date)
                 customer(inv.customer)
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
println groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
```

You can try it on-line <kbd>[demo](https://ideone.com/TVwik8)</kbd> quickly

Comment: Thanks Rao..the code sure works.However the data seems hardcoded.. can we define Maps dynamically?Is there any alternate way?

Comment: @SantanuGhosh, You can read and create data structure as mentioned in the answer. By the way, that was to show you can create xml & how you loop thru the data. Appreciate if you can accept it as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) if that solves your problem.

Comment: Could please guide me to create a list of maps of such dynamic elements.

Comment: You could see the list of maps in `data` object.